# Matlab Combine Row Vectors into one row

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there a vectorized, automated way to fill a row vector `l` times with repeating numbers `x` such that `x` is increased by `y` after a certain number `k` of elements? `k, l, x, and y` are given.

**Two examples:**

```
(k = 4, l = 4, x = 0, y = 1): $A = [0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2; 3 3 3 3];$

(k = 2, l = 3, x = 0, y = 0.1): $B = [0 0; 0.1 0.1; 0.2 0.2]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use repmat together with a:b

This way your fist example would look like this:

```
repmat((0:3)', 1,4)
```

The second one:

```
repmat((0:0.1:0.2)', 1,2)
```

You can also try linspace or similar functions to be as close to what you want as possible